# Python evaluates comparison of integer and character with the same value as False

Tags: python, integer, character, comparison-operators

I ran into this interesting little 'gotcha' this evening, consider the following code snippet:

( chr(1) == 1 )

This comparison evaluates to False on Python 2.7.4, is this a feature or a bug?, If a feature, can anyone explain the reasoning behind this design decision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no "char" type in python, `chr` returns a string of length one, and with strong typing it doesn't make sense for any string to be equal to any integer.

Comment: Ah, my bad, too much time in C and C++ environments :)